# Counting characters in txt file giving wrong count

Tags: c++, counter

I am learning C++ and right now I have made a file that does some encrypting/decrypting. After I am done with everything, I want to find out how much a file was compressed/decompressed. So I decided to count the characters in the input and output file, but here's where it starts going wrong.

```
int get_compression(string file1, string file2){
    string line = "";
    ifstream stream1(file1.c_str());
    double counter1 = 0.0;
    while(getline(stream1, line)){
        counter1 += line.length();
    }
    stream1.close();

    cout << counter1 << "\n";

    ifstream stream2(file2.c_str());
    double counter2 = 0.0;
    while(getline(stream2, line)){
        counter2 += line.length();
    }
    stream2.close();

    cout << counter2 << "\n";

    return (counter2/counter1)*100;
}
```

I have added the two `cout` statements to see what it has counted, but it is telling me it has counted 496 characters in the input txt file that really has 528 characters, and 481 characters in the txt file that has 785 characters. Did I make some rookie mistake somewhere?

Comment: `getline` discards the end-of-line character. This might be two characters on aome OSes. For a reliable count, use `fstat`.

Comment: @Jongware I would be fine with the count being off by two characters, but it is off by several hundred with my output txt file.

Comment: You will also need to open the file in binary mode, since if its in text mode you will get some auto translations hiding bytes.

Comment: @Chronicle: It's losing a character for *every* line you read. If you're on Windows, it (probably) losing another character for each line by translating a CR/LF combination to a new-line.

Comment: assuming its a text file, the above code wont count newlines, that could be 2 chars per line that it will be off by.

Comment: Count the number of *lines* and output that as well. See if your first example contains 32 (or possibly, 16) lines.

Comment: @Jongware The first example contains 42 lines, of which 16 are empty lines. It could be that the 16 empty lines are not being counted, and I will see if I can add that to my counter. However, that does not explain the second example, which has 42 lines of which 16 are empty as well, yet the count is off by 304 characters.

Comment: `stream.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end); auto fileSize = stream.tellg();`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are not counting the new line characters. On Windows it may occur 2 characters per line error. So I suggest that you have a look at how many lines does each file has and added to what your code has counted.

Comment: Not actually "on Windows", as the input file may originate from another OS -- or, alternatively, it was created with a tool that does not care for Windows Only "cr/lf" line ends.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers and comments are perfectly accurate, but you might want to try using Boost Filesystem because it makes things like this so much easier.

This is an example taken from the boost documentation at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/tutorial.html#Reporting-size

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (argc < 2)
  {
    std::cout << "Usage: tut1 path\n";
    return 1;
  }
  std::cout << argv[1] << " " << file_size(argv[1]) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```